# send multiple messages to one channel in go for collating

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to wrap my mind around go. I want to make a simple program that basically

1. starts a bunch of go routines
2. process messages
3. sends the processed result to a channel
4. have the main thread collect these results
5. shut down.

Seems simple. I started with no logic at all. I just send a number and try to get that number back.

issue: I'm deadlocking and I'm not sure why. I think I might be misusing wait groups with channels, because they work individually, but I'm not sure how to get the main thread to block on an arbitrary number of initiated go routines.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    queue := make(chan int)
    start := time.Now()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < 10; i += 1 {
        wg.Add(1)
        go count(i, queue, &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    for value := range queue {
        println(value)
    }

    close(queue)

    fmt.Println(time.Now().Sub(start))
    // fmt.Println(summation)
}

func count(number int, queue chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    fmt.Println("Starting ", number)
    queue <- number
    fmt.Println("ending")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your goroutines block on `queue <- number` because `queue` is an unbuffered channel and nobody is reading from it, as main blocks on `wg.Wait`.

Declare `queue` as a buffered channel instead. For example: `queue := make(chan int, 10)`

From the [Go Tour (concurrency)](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) and subsequent page:

> By default, sends and receives block until the other side is ready. This allows goroutines to synchronize without explicit locks or condition variables.

> Sends to a buffered channel block only when the buffer is full. Receives block when the buffer is empty.

Alternatively, move `wg.Wait` after the `for v := range queue` loop.

Comment: this makes sense thanks. I did try the `wait` after the range, but you wind up with a similar problem of threads deadlocking.

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type event struct {
    data      chan string
    numWorker int
}

func (e event) Send() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    // Spaw numWorker goroutines that sends message to
    // the same channel.
    for i := 0; i < e.numWorker; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(id int) {
            // Do some fake work
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            e.data <- fmt.Sprintf("message from go #%d", id)
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    // Wait for goroutines to finish their work.
    wg.Wait()
    // Close the channel to signal Recv to stop ranging
    // over the channel.
    close(e.data)
}

func (e event) Recv() {
    // Range over the data channel to receive message(s).
    for msg := range e.data {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}

func main() {
    e := event{
        numWorker: 10, // Number of worker goroutine(s)
        data:      make(chan string, 5 /* Buffer Size */),
    }
    // Spawn a goroutine for Send
    go e.Send()
    // Recv receives data from Send
    e.Recv()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid deadlocking you can manage the channel and wait groups in separate goroutine. Try change that:

```
    wg.Wait()

    for value := range queue {
        println(value)
    }

    close(queue)
```

with this:

```
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(queue)
    }()
    for value := range queue {
        println(value)
    }
```